# Exporting symbols when compiling DLL - MSVC

Tags: c, visual-c++, cmake

I have a shared library which uses CMake as build system. It compiles fine on Linux machines with GCC. Now I am trying to compile on windows. MSVC won't export the symbols until specified. I am aware about `__declspec(dllexport)`. But the example provided in the CMake wiki is confusing. Please consider the following code.

```
#if defined (_WIN32) 
  #if defined(MyLibrary_EXPORTS)
    #define  MYLIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllexport)
  #else
    #define  MYLIB_EXPORT __declspec(dllimport)
  #endif /* MyLibrary_EXPORTS */
#else /* defined (_WIN32) */
 #define MYLIB_EXPORT
#endif
```

I understand `__declspec(dllexport)` but wondering why `__declspec(dllimport)` is used?  Also how do I use this? Is it like `MYLIB_EXPORT void function()`?

Consider I have C function named `foo()`. This internally uses several `static` functions. When exporting do I need to export the static functions too? Or is it enough to export only the entry functions that are part of API?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is enough to export only the entry functions which are a part of API. No need to export static functions.

Also, no need to use __declspec(dllimport) for functions. It is needed only for data. Windows will automatically take care of doing the import incase of functions.

The below links can be helpful:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(VS.80).aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682589(VS.85).aspx

Answer (score 1):

That's typically used for a header file that's used both by your library to compile and by its clients; when you include the header in your library you define `MyLibrary_EXPORTS` and it will export the symbols, when you include the header in a client app it will import them instead.

No, you only need to export the API entry points - you don't need to export the static functions.